# MYSQL: How to write sql query to find minimum value but with count of same value with count of Category

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I want to write query to check how many minimum value with same value exists and count of each category.
Table data looks like this

```
Id  CatId   value
1    1      2.3
2    1      2.3
3    2      1.1
4    1      4.2
5    2      1.5
6    3      8.1
7    1      3.3
8    3      4.2
9    2      1.9
```

The query should return rows like

```
CatId   min(value)  count_with_same_min_value  count(CatId)
1           2.3         2                         4          
2           1.1         1                         3
3           4.2         1                         2
```

Thanks

Comment: So go ahead and write that query

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a subquery:

```
select c.catid, min(c.value),
       sum(c.value = cmin.minval),
       count(c.CatId)
from category c join
     (select catid, min(value) as minval
      from category
      group by catid
     ) cmin
     on c.catid = cmin.catid
group by c.catid;
```

Or with a `select` within a select:

```
select catid, min(value),
       (select count(*) from category c2 where c2.value = min(c.value)),
       count(CatId)
from category c
group by catid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT x.catid
      , MIN(value) a
      , COUNT(y.catid) b
      , COUNT(*) c
   FROM my_table x 
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT catid
             , MIN(value) min_value 
          FROM my_table 
         GROUP 
            BY catid
      ) y 
     ON y.catid = x.catid 
    AND y.min_value = x.value 
  GROUP 
     BY catid;
```

Comment: Why? Seems an odd request.

Comment: let say there is only one table. i want without join

Comment: You need either a join or correlated subquery, as in Gordon Linoff's answer. My experience is that MySQL executes JOINs more efficiently.

Comment: there's only one table in my solution